# Dagger2 @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type with interface and implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a class that implements the interface `java.util.function.Function` that I'd like to inject for use in another class using Dagger2:

```
class MyUsefulClass @Inject constructor() : Function<List<String>, String> {

    override fun apply(lines: List<String>): String {
        // Do stuff 
        return ""
    }
}
```

Usually, I'd declare an `@Binds` declaration in the module class like so:

```
@Module
interface MyModule {

    @Binds
    fun provideMyUsefulClass(concretion: MyUsefulClass): Function<List<String>, String>
}
```

This approach has served me well for all the other classes I have in my project that implement this interface but in this *one* instance, I'm greeted by the error message:

`@Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type…`

What's funny is that changing the return type of the class and the `@Binds` declaration to `Function<MutableList<String>, String>` from `Function<List<String>, String>` works and everything compiles fine.

What am I missing here? The error message is clearly untrue. Is there some massive gotcha I'm unaware of here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect this might be a case of "missing" @JvmSuppressWildcards, whereby kotlin adds some `? extends String` in the `List` type  and that makes the dagger compiler fail (the error message should contain some more hints).

I guess you need to change your function type to `Function<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards String>, String>` where you use it.

It's a known annoyance, you can read something more in detail here:
https://medium.com/@naturalwarren/dagger-kotlin-3b03c8dd6e9b

I suspect that `MutableList` doesn't have that problem because you can both 'read' and 'write' strings with it.

Comment: That is indeed, incredibly annoying. I really wish the error messages were more descriptive here. Thank you for your answer. I've added a few more references below for anyone stumbling upon this question later:


- [Kotlin/ Dagger annoyances](https://adavis.info/2017/08/jvmsuppresswildcards-biggest-annoyance-kotlin.html)


- [This article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/dagger-in-kotlin-gotchas-and-optimizations-7446d8dfd7dc) from Dev Relations at Google claims that version 2.25 of Dagger fixes this issue but this appears not to be the case as I've just reproduced it using `v2.26`

Comment: lol I've made a comment on someone citing that article already. I think it's a mistake in the article, they've removed the requirement for `field:` on properties. But not this case.